# How do I count the occurrences of each word in each of sentences stored in arraylists?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, word-count

I have an `arraylist` that holds each line of a document for example-

```
list.add("I like to play pool")

list.add("How far can you run")

list.add("Do you like fanta because I like fanta")
```

I want to be able to go through each sentence stored in the `arrayList` and count the occurrence of each word in each of the sentences, can anyone help me?

EDIT
This is what I tried but it only tells me the occurrence of EACH sentence. I need it to be able to count the words for each sentence.

```
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(list);
        for (String key : unique) {
            System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, key));
```

Comment: We help those who help themselves. You haven't even tried.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: If you have any code you tried please post here.

Comment: Sorry I added what I tried, hopefully it makes sense what i'm looking to do. I'm relatively new to programming.

Comment: Please read an interesting article [ask] and try to provide [mcve] in each question,

Comment: there are several solutions for your question, but since your question is a typical example for map-reduce programming paradigm, I suggest you take a look at it and then see its implementation  in java 8, as Mureinik provided in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Lets call your `ArrayList<String> list`.
2. Let's make a list list2 of String[]
   3, Split Sentences to the array.
3. Count occurrences

The code:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
//add sentences here
list.add("My first sentence sentence");
list.add("My second sentence1 sentence1");

ArrayList<String[]> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : list) { list2.add(s.split(" "));};
for (String[] s : list2) {
    Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String word : s) {
        Integer count = wordCounts.get(word);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        wordCounts.put(word, count + 1);
    }
    for (String key : wordCounts.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + ": " + wordCounts.get(key).toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this help! Seems to be spot on, only when it prints out the sentence is no longer in order but it gives me the results I needed!

Comment: Feel free to modify this code I gave you so it prints stuff in a way you'd appreciate.

It's a good manner to upvote the answer you marked as a solution.

Comment: try replacing HashMap<String, Integer>(); with LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>(); to get them in order